# Build array from an output

Tags: perl, scripting, vmware

I am trying to create a script that will take output of a system command and I want to organize the data into an array.

The script is to discover VMs residing on a local ESXi server I have. I am using plink.exe to send the command to the server and then it returns a list of VMs that looks like this.

```
Vmid   Name                File                 Guest OS      Version   Annotation
128    NS01    [datastore2] NS01/NS01.vmx     ubuntu64Guest   vmx-07
144    NS02    [datastore2] NS02/NS02.vmx     ubuntu64Guest   vmx-07
208    MX01    [datastore2] MX01/MX01.vmx     ubuntu64Guest   vmx-07
224    SQL01   [datastore2] SQL01/SQL01.vmx   ubuntu64Guest   vmx-07
240    WS01    [datastore2] WS01/WS01.vmx     ubuntu64Guest   vmx-07
```

How would I take this and make an array out of it? The only columns that really matter are VMID, Name, File

The command I am using to get the output is this.

```
# Parse ESX\ESXi server for virtual machines that reside on it
system ("$plink \-batch \-pw $esx_password $esx_user\@$esx_host vim-cmdvmsvc/getallvms\n");
```

Any insight would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use *backquotes* not `system` if you want to parse the output.

```
my $cmd 
    = "$plink -batch -pw $esx_password $esx_user\@$esx_host "
    . "vim-cmdvmsvc/getallvms"
    ;
my @lines = `$cmd`;
```

`system` will just use your standard out.

Not sure why you were escaping the dashes, though...

Once you have the output, you can do the following (note that I leveraged the fixed-length fields look):

```
foreach ( @line ) { 
    # this is the get-it-and-do-something-else-with-it version
    my ( $vmid, $name, $file )
        = substr( $_, 0, 47 ) =~ m/^ ( \d+ ) \s+ ( \S+ ) \s+ (.*\S) \s* $/x
        ;

    # OR the store-it-in-an-array-of-hashes version:
    @{ my $h = {}}{ qw<VMID Name File> }
        = substr( $_, 0, 47 ) =~ m/^ ( \d+ ) \s+ ( \S+ ) \s+ (.*\S) \s* $/x
        ;
    push @array, $h if %$h;
}
```

Comment: I was escaping them because it kept yelling at me. I was saying that - was an operator and the @ was being treated as an array.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! And a fun little side effect is [0] is the headings of the various columns which I was going to omit anyway so its a win win.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the data columns will contain spaces, you could easily `split(/\n/)` the output into lines, iterate over those, and `split(/\s+/)` the rows into arrays.  Then extract the columns you are interested in, by index.

Comment: do you mean the blank horizontal lines between each result?

Comment: No, I mean that the data fields themselves could not contain spaces, or the split(/\s+/) function will return two separate fields for such data.  For example, the last row would be parsed as ('240', 'WS01', '[datastore2]', 'WS01/WS01.vmx', 'ubuntu64Guest', 'vmx-07').  If there was a space in "WS01/WS01.vmx" that would yield two fields, resulting in 7 fields instead of 6.  For blank lines, you can just test if the array returned by split(/\s+/) has enough elements -- if not, skip it.

Comment: That is perfect. After I get basics of everything down, then I will want to combine [datastore] and server/server.vmx into /datastore/server/server.vmx to reflect its path on the system. But this is a for time when I actually understand regex further.

Comment: Also, it looks like the fields may in fact be separated by tabs, not spaces.  Test with split(/\t/) first and see if that works like you want it to.

Comment: yes I remember from a sample line I found a a shell script they filtered by tabs and it worked perfect.