# Extracting specific data tokens from perl array

Tags: perl, vmware

I am trying to extract specific data tokens from a perl array. This is pretty much an extension of my previous question about building an array from a command output.

I tried working with an expression given to me by a user. It works! but it uses fixed length fields and after some research to find out what that meant I found out it will not work for me.

Is there anyway to take the same expression and remove the fixed length fields.

Here is the code I got from the [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138544/build-array-from-an-output).

```
foreach ( @line ) { 
# this is the get-it-and-do-something-else-with-it version
my ( $vmid, $name, $file )
    = substr( $_, 0, 47 ) =~ m/^ ( \d+ ) \s+ ( \S+ ) \s+ (.*\S) \s* $/x
    ;
```

The best outcome would be being able to tie the various match to $1,$2,$3,etc.

Comment: In what way does this not work for you? Maybe you could give examples of lines you are trying to parse where fixed-length fields aren't working.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you looked at the various regex references in perldoc?

Comment: http://www.regexbuddy.com/ there's also free analogs

Answer (score 1):

I supplied the answer, contingent on the idea that the format was fixed-length. If this doesn't work then, for sanity's sake we need to make another assumption. This one goes along the lines that the first two captures are alright, but that the third can't be used because it depends on fixed-length format.

#### No-space-in-Filename Assumption

So the new assumption is the following sequence:

- a `'['` character
- followed by any number of non-`'['` characters
- followed by a closing `']'` character
- followed by whitespace
- followed by a file specified by *non-whitespace characters*

Then this should work:

```
my ( $vmid, $name, $file )
    = m/^ ( \d+ ) \s+ ( \S+ ) \s+ ( [[] [^\]]+ [\]] \s+ \S+) /x
    ;
```

#### 'Nix Filenames

But the reason I didn't suggest this at first is that *NIX files can contain spaces, and the columns looked contained by the fixed-width assumption. So I tried to avoid some unknown complexity with a simple pragmatic assumption about the data.

And that is a single space in the file name differentiated by multiple spaces in the output. I'll show that below, but if the data uses spaces in the file names and spaces to separate columns *AND* allows spaces in the Guest OS, Version or Annotation fields. Then you're not going to get what you want by a regex.

#### Single-space only Assumption

Here's the single-space assumption:

```
m/^ ( \d+ ) \s+ ( \S+ ) \s+ ( \[ [^\]]+ \] \s+ \S+ (?: [ ] \S+ )* )  /x
```

#### *Ye-argh!!* OR Brute force method

The more difficult case can be covered by the following (more) special-case code:

```
my ( $vmid, $name, $file_haystack )
    = m/^ ( \d+ ) \s+ ( \S+ ) \s+ (.*\S) \s* $/x
    ;
my @file_parts = split ' ', $file_haystack;
my $file_name  = shift @file_parts; 
while ( @file_parts and !-d $file_name ) { 
    $file_name .= ' ' . shift @file_parts;
}
```

***However***, that *assumes* the file *exists* on the system that you're reading the output from. If that is not the case, you might make the dot-vmx assumption:

```
m/^ ( \d+ ) \s+ ( \S+ ) \s+ ( \[ [^\]]+ \] \s+ .* [.]vmx ) \s /x
```

#### This all might be moot *OR* You're closer to the data than I am

Of course this might all be moot because, perhaps you can pass a command to your script to make the columns unambiguous, say, like in a CVS format. Or perhaps if it prints a path with spaces in it, it will print double quotes around it. *OR* perhaps you can make it display spaces in the path name with *escapes* preceding them.

Double-quote asssumption:

```
m/^ ( \d+ ) \s+ ( \S+ ) \s+ ( \[ [^\]]+ \] \s+ (?:" [^"]+ " | \S+ ))/x
```

Excaped space assumption:

```
m/^ ( \d+ ) \s+ ( \S+ ) \s+ ( \[ [^\]]+ \] \s+ (?: [^\s\\]+ | (\\\\)*\\. )/x
```

If the reporting program has not put rules around the output--or if your internal process has not put rules around it's lack of rules, then foolproof assumptions cannot be made.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly obfuscated so you will be motivated to learn basic language features:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use YAML;

my @data;

m{^
  (?<vmid> \d+)
  [ ]+
  (?<name> \w+)
  \s+
  (?<file> \[\w+\][ ]\S+)
  \s+
  (?<os> \w+)
  \s+
  (?<version> \S+)
}x and push @data, { %+ } while <DATA>;

print Dump \@data;

__DATA__
Vmid   Name                File                 Guest OS      Version   Annotation
128    NS01    [datastore2] NS01/NS01.vmx     ubuntu64Guest   vmx-07
144    NS02    [datastore2] NS02/NS02.vmx     ubuntu64Guest   vmx-07
208    MX01    [datastore2] MX01/MX01.vmx     ubuntu64Guest   vmx-07
224    SQL01   [datastore2] SQL01/SQL01.vmx   ubuntu64Guest   vmx-07
240    WS01    [datastore2] WS01/WS01.vmx     ubuntu64Guest   vmx-07
```

Comment: thank you for the assistance. this will give me the piece i need. now i need to hit the books and learn the the rest.